# raspberry-pi with streaming-FPV

Tags: image-processing, raspberry-pi

I have project Where  I will use raspberry with its camera in processes motion detection then , I wana stream it by **FPV** (First-person view )
My question Is there any ability to use raspberry as Camera module to send the images BY FPV's sender (5.8 Ghz)

thank in advance

Comment: what is FPV sender ? what is this 5.8Ghz you are talking about. Please be clear about what you want to know. What is the frame rate and resolution you need.

Comment: if you ask like that the answer is: yes

Comment: Fpv is a system module , which is used as broadcaster

Comment: @Piglet unfortunately , I couldn't find its way

Comment: then you should improve your question. read [ask]. you ask if it is possible, now how you can achieve it. you question also lacks a lot of requirements that would be necessary to give a meaningful answer.
framerate, resolution, which fpv sender and how to interface it...